# Selenoid - Emulating mobile in ChromeDriver / Python

Tags: python, selenium-chromedriver, selenoid

I try to set `experimental_option` on ChromeDriver by Selenoid UI. I tried a lot of cases but neither works, usually, I see a normal browser without mobile emulation in local Selenoid UI or browser is set as unknown when I try another way and I don't have a `capabilities` dictionary.

My code now, which doesn't work correctly:

```
        capabilities = {
            "browserName": "chrome",
            "version": "80.0",
            "enableVNC": True,
            "enableVideo": video,
            'screenResolution': "1920x1080",
            "chromeOptions": {
                "mobileEmulation": {
                    "deviceName": "Nexus 5"
                }
            }
        }

        context.browser = webdriver.Remote(
            command_executor="http://selenoid:4444/wd/hub",
            desired_capabilities=capabilities)
```

Maybe somebody knows how to set experimental options in the chrome image in Selenoid UI?

Comment: Should now be `goog:chromeOptions` instead of just `chromeOptions`.

Comment: @vania-pooh Works! Thank's a lot!:)